# ldapmodify TLS: certificate is not valid - error -8179:Peer's Certificate issuer is not recognized

Tags: active-directory, ssl, ldap, ssl-certificate, openldap

In trying to connect to an MS active directory server over ssl, I am trying to run this:

```
ldapmodify -vv -H 'ldaps://abc.def.com:636' -D 'cn=user,cn=Users,dc=abc,dc=def,dc=com' -f test.ldif -w 'password' -d4
```

I get this:

```
ldap_initialize( ldaps://abc.def.com:636/??base ) 
TLS: certificate [CN=**********] is not valid - error -8179:Peer's Certificate issuer is not recognized..
```

However this works:

```
ldapsearch -H 'ldaps://abc.def.com:636' -D 'cn=user,cn=Users,dc=abc,dc=def,dc=com' -w 'password' -b 'dc=abc,dc=def,dc=com
```

My /etc/openldap/ldap.conf looks like this:

```
TLS_REQCERT never
TLS_CACERTDIR /etc/openldap/certs
```

I ignored the certificate, why does it ask again?